# Getting datas from past months

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

i have following table (product table):

```
productid    status      started      terminated    break_begin    break_end    value  
 1           active      2020-01-01                                              15  
 2           terminated  2020-02-04   2020-04-06                                 10  
 3           active      2020-01-15                 2020-02-15     20-02-29      5  
 4           paused      2020-02-01                 2020-04-15     20-04-30      25  
 5           terminated  2019-12-31   2020-03-21                                 20  
 6           active      2020-04-01                                              12
```

So if i want to know which products are currently active, i will filter by `status` ->   `status= 'active'`

But if i want to know which products where active last month in march(lets say at the last day of march), i cant filter by status anymore. Because the status of a product will change by time depending the product is paused, terminated or not even started.
A product is active when:

- When the product is started
- when the product is not terminated
- and when the product is not in a break

So i have to do something like this in the `where clause`:

```
where started <= '2020-03-31' AND terminated IS NULL or terminated > '2020-03-31' AND ........
```

Since im looking just on the last day of a month, i make sure that the product started before that date and that there is no terminated_date before that date and there is also no break during that date.

I could do this for February or for any other month.

But my `goal` is to get a list for a set of month and not for a single month. I want the `SUM` of `value` of all active products for the last 4 months.

Like this (numbers are just examples):

```
January  February   March   April  
32        47         50      40
```

My first idea is to get a list of months with the last day:

```
generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, NOW(),'1 month')
```

And calculate then the last day of each month.
After that, i would use that calculated field for the conditions in the `where clause`

Im not sure if this is the right way do to that. I already tried it but im kinda stucked.

`Explanation: When a product is active:`

A product is active till it get terminated or the product is currently in a break(pause)
For example we look at the product with the `id 2`
`started` -> 4th February
`terminated` -> 4th April
So from 4th Feb till 4th April the product was active. Since 4th April the product is terminated

Comment: You have four columns with dates which makes this question really hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rows associated with each product as of the last day of the month using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (gs.date, t.product_id) gs.date + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day' as month,
       t.*
from t join
     generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, now(), '1 month') gs(dte)
     on t.started <= gs.date + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
order by gs.date, t.product_id;
```

This may answer your question.  If not, you can use this as a subquery or CTE.  I find the explanation of what is active to be hard to follow.

Comment: Could probably answer my question. If i group this by `gs.date` like `date_trunc('month',gs.date)`, this will compare that part `on t.started <= gs.date + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day`for every month i guess ?

Comment: The query would be equivalent if you aggregated by `gs.date + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'` (or month).  This will return a separate row for each month generated by the `generate_series()`.